# Define closest markers (previous & next) while mouse_over event occurs on polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I have a polyline which consists of 10 markers.
Is there a way to define closest markers (previous & next) while mouse_over or mouse_click event occurs on some part of polyline?

For example, I have clicked on 1 part of polyline. This part of polyline is between 2 markers. I need to search 2 markers with theirs LatLng positions.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

**Update1**
Here is the snippet1 (getting latlng for each marker from the Database (from server's API)):

```
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                    json.coordinate.latitude,//getting from response from server's API
                    json.coordinate.longitude
                    ),
            map: this.map,
            timestamp: json.timestamp
        });
markersArray.push(marker);
```

And snippet2 (Filling array of markers and drawing a polyline):

```
var latlngs = []; //get locations (latLng) from markers
    for (var i in markersArray) {
    latlngs.push(markersArray[i].getPosition());
    }
var lineSymbol = {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW
        };

        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: latlngs,
            /*icons: [{
             icon: lineSymbol,
             offset: '100%'
             }],*/
            strokeColor: "#000000",
            map: this.map
        })

        google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseover', function(event)
        {
            //TODO: ???
        });
```

Be honest, I need next four things:
1. Hover the mouse over the polyline
2. Define prev/next markers between the polyline mouse_over event occured
3. Get marker.timestamp values from these markers
4. Draw direction (as google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW) ONLY for this part of polyline (not for all polyline)

Comment: The answer is yes, there is a way. What does your code look like?  How is your polyline defined?  How do you add the markers?

Comment: [example with markers on a polyline with next/previous links](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_geodesic_proj.html) (the little red markers), not exactly what you are looking for, consider it a proof of concept...

Comment: I saw that example, but I'm not sure it can help me...

Comment: All of your updated requirements can be implemented.  And you are correct, that example doesn't help you with #1 or #2, but they weren't there before.  Given the updated requirements, start with #1 & 2 (find the 2 closest markers on mouseover of the polyline), the rest should follow from that.

Comment: OK, the 1st question is implemented in the bottom of my snippet#2. How can I implement the 2nd one?

Thanks for your answers, geocodezip, your efforts are really appreciated.